# Replace null with empty String decorator

Tags: java, cactoos

Is there in Cactoos framework some Text decorator (or maybe some other way), which replace null string with empty string? Like Strings.nullToEmpty function in Google Guava.

I have found NoNulls decorator, but I need just replacement without throwing exception.

So it must look like this:

```
String someNullString = null; 
new StrictEmptyText(
 new TextOf(someNullString) // this row produces NPE for now
).asString(); // ""
```

Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no `Text` implementation that does this for you in a direct way.

Using pure cactoos:

```
new TextOf(
  new UncheckedScalar<>(
    new Ternary<>(
      someNullString != null,
      someNullString,
      ""
    )
  ).value()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Optional::ofNullable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-) from Java 8 like so :

```
String str = Optional.ofNullable(someNullString)
        .orElse(""); // return empty if someNullString is null or someNullString if not null
```